# jCarousel center the active item

Tags: jquery, center, jcarousel

Is it possible to center the active item in jCarousel and give the active item a class name?

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/609w5gkL/][1]
```

In the documantion is standing 'center:true' but thats not working for me...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Duplicate question: [jcarousel custom class on current slide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21000589/jcarousel-custom-class-on-current-slide)

You you need to pass in the "center:true" option underneath the first option you already have when you initialize jCarousel. I've added the option and now they are centered.

```
jQuery('.slider').jcarousel({
    wrap: 'both',
    center: true
});
```

I've updated the code for you to add an "active" class too using the example link above. You may wish to clean up the code a bit yourself.

Before you ask a question on Stack - do a quick search on here first. Chances are someones already answered the question you have.

Here is an updated fiddle which adds your requests:

http://jsfiddle.net/609w5gkL/2/

Comment: What white row are you referring to? I can see your headers and they are absolute positioned. Are you trying to center the headers? 
Also my fiddle adds the active class you asked for in your original question - why have you down voted my answer when it fixes your request? 
If you can better describe what you are centering I may be able to help you.

Comment: Can you update your fiddle and add your headers and styling there? It's far easier to debug when the code is isolated.

Comment: The carousel slide displays in the correct position when you adjust the viewport. I would suggest trying to initialize the slider on window.load instead of document.ready. E.g 

jquery(window).load(function() {}

Failing that try using the reload method to refresh the slider - it looks like an issue caused on page load. The reload method is detailed here: http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/docs/reference/api.html#reload